# Why KYDrawerController do not show when code fired from Alamofire response?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, alamofire

I'm using KYDrawerController to show side menu on the main screen when logging in success.

I use Alamofire to request the authentication of the user, when the response is a success then open the main screen with a drawer.

The problem is the the main screen doesnt show up or the login screen stay still, But when call the code from outside the Alamofire response, it works just fine.
Here is my code

```
Alamofire.request(URL_LOGIN_PHONE, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {  response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let jsonResponse = JSON(value)

            // Check if status = success
            if jsonResponse["status"] == "success" {

        // Init Drawer
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

        let navVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavVC")  // is the main controller for the drawer.
        let drawerVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerVC")  // is the drawer, and the drawer needs a main controller

        appDelegate.drawerController.mainViewController = navVC
        appDelegate.drawerController.drawerViewController = drawerVC

        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = appDelegate.drawerController
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            } else {

            }

        case .failure( _):
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the code in a async closure block, like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 // Init Drawer
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    let navVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavVC")  // is the main controller for the drawer.
    let drawerVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerVC")  // is the drawer, and the drawer needs a main controller

    appDelegate.drawerController.mainViewController = navVC
    appDelegate.drawerController.drawerViewController = drawerVC

    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = appDelegate.drawerController
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to know if the drawer is opened or not?

Comment: Adding this `self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)` before the rootViewController line

Comment: The window and drawerController are declared in AppDelegate.

Comment: Sorry, i mean this line `appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)` above the rootViewController line

Comment: Thanks for your time but I found the solution.

Comment: should share it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to Alamofire or main thread, simply the code was trying to instantiate a drawer that already loaded. So I added code to check if its loaded or not. if already loaded I used unwindSegue to return to the main view controller.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        // check if drawer loaded or not.
        if appDelegate.drawerController.isViewLoaded {
            // Drawer loaded prevoiusly, dont load it again
            appDelegate.drawerController.setDrawerState(.closed, animated: true)
            self.exitToRestaurants()
        } else {
            // Drawer not loaded from prevouis use.
            // and it will be loaded for the first time/
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

            let navVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavVC")  // is the main controller for the drawer.
            let drawerVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerVC")  // is the drawer, and the drawer needs a main controller


            appDelegate.drawerController.mainViewController = navVC
            appDelegate.drawerController.drawerViewController = drawerVC

            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = appDelegate.drawerController
            appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```